# Is there a way to view your standings on Clash Royale global tournament?

Tags: clash-royale

So on clash royale gobal tournament I think I have a chance to battle and qualify for the top 100 to earn an emote and the 100k gold. My questions is I dont know how many wins I need for top 100, as it only shows up to 50. Is there a way to find the current standings, like a website or something? thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Clash Royale does not provide any information after the top 100.

---

There are *some* websites that do provide the data you desire.

One of those is [RoyaleApi.com](https://royaleapi.com/about):

- [RoyaleApi Global Tournament Leaderboard](https://royaleapi.com/players/gt/leaderboard)

Which gives wins, loses, change and the deck of the **top 1000 players**.

---

RoyaleApi also provides a Public API for Clash Royale data: [Docs.RoyaleApi.com](https://docs.royaleapi.com/#/) which can be used to create your own (eg) leaderboard of global tournaments.